# Varnish port 80, не может общаться с NGINX port 81

Tags: nginx, веб-сервер, vps

VPS

OS: Debian

Из софта только:

Varnish port 80

NGINX port 81

php-fpm

MariaDB

Drupal 7

Файервола нет.

Установка основывалась на официальном [руководстве](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/4.1/tutorial/putting_varnish_on_port_80.html)

Varnish status:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Лог: tail /var/log/varnish/varnishncsa.log

[19/Jun/2018:13:41:52 +0300] "GET http://185.75.90.197:6081/misc/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 5430 "http://185.75.90.197:6081/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.117 Safari/537.36"

конфиг: /etc/default/varnish

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,256m"
```

конфиг: /etc/varnish/default.vcl

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "81";
}
```

nginx:

```
server {
     listen 81;
}
```

Если Nginx поставить на порт 80, то все нормально работает, может чего не донастроил на своем VPS?

Comment: Информации маловато, поэтому всё может быть. Nginx сам по себе на 81-м порту отвечает с локали/снаружи?

Comment: Отвечает снаружи

Comment: Так а где видно, что Варниш слушает на 80-м порту, а также завязан на бэкенд (nginx) по 81-му? Приведенный скриншот и логи говорят только про стандартный порт 6081.

Comment: отредактировал вопрос, добавил данные конфигурационных файлов.

Comment: Ок. На скриншоте ясно видно, что варниш слушает на порту 6081, следовательно, конфиг либо игнорируется, либо значения переопределяются (например, другим конфигом).

Comment: это понятно, но как выявить причину игнорирования?

Comment: Я бы начал с поиска мануала (желательно официального) по настройке этого ПО для моего дистрибутива. Может оказаться, что файл конфигурации совсем в другом месте, либо еще какая особенность... логи варниша изучил бы при рестарте, вдруг какая информация есть...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varnish отказывался менять порт с 6081 по умолчанию, на 80 т.к. руководство немного отстает от версии varnish 5.0.0, в котором используется systemd вместо init.d как init system.

Необходимо переопределить сценарий инициализации.

```
# cp /lib/systemd/system/varnish.service /etc/systemd/system/
# nano /etc/systemd/system/varnish.service
```

изменить порт

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
```

Перезагружаем:

```
 # systemctl reload varnish.service
```

возникает ошибка

```
Failed to reload varnish.service: Job type reload is not applicable for unit varnish.service.
See system logs and 'systemctl status varnish.service' for details.
```

Сначала:

```
/usr/share/varnish/reload-vcl
```

Затем:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Затем:

```
systemctl restart varnish
```

Теперь работает.

```
curl -I http://localhost:80

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.13.3
Date: Wed, 20 Jun 2018 07:42:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Language: en
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
X-Generator: Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-Varnish: 2
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.0)
Connection: keep-alive
```

Решение взято отсюда: https://konkretor.com/2017/05/22/varnish-nginx-with-ssl-install-under-ubuntu-16-04/ и https://www.varnish-software.com/wiki/content/tutorials/varnish/varnish_ubuntu.html